# Has laravel 7 model a way to get list of all columns?

Tags: laravel

Has laravel 7 model a way to get list of all columns ?

I found and tried method

```
  with(new ModelName)->columns
```

but it returns empty string.
I do not mean $fillable var of a model.

Thanks!

Comment: something like? `$product = new Product;`
`$columns = $product->getTableColumns();`

Comment: Does it work  only for model already  loaded ? I tried to use it in a scope :      public function scopeExcludeFields($query,$value = array())
    {
        return $query->select( array_diff( with(new Task)->getTableColumns(),(array) $value) );
>getTableColumns(); 
    }
. But got Call to undefined method error

Comment: this can help https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/get-table-column-names-as-array-from-eloquent-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a reliable way to pull the list of attributes from any given instance no matter the state, and assuming the table structure isn't changing often, the path of least resistance might be to set a defaults attributes array to ensure the attributes are always present.

e.g.

```
class Fish extends Model
{
     protected $attributes = [
        'uuid' => null,
        'fin_count' => null,
        'first_name' => null,
    ];
}
```

- $fishie = app(\Fish::class);

will then result in an instance of Fish with uuid, fin_count, and first_name set. You can then use `$fishie->attributes` or `$fishie->getAttributes()` to load the full set.

Assuming the structure doesn't change a lot, setting the attributes on the model like this will save you a database query every time you want to reference the list. The flip side is that instances change from not having the attributes unless explicitly defined to always being present, which may have implications in the project.

Here's the documentation for default attributes:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#default-attribute-values